# Dual dropdown listbox page redirection php wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I was thinking about creating a page where the user gets to choose from two drop-down lists and based on his choice clicks the "Go" button to be redirected.

So for example, if we got 5 teachers and 5 subjects the odds will be 5x5=25 pages.

eg: Select teacher: ..A... , Select class: ..X..... , Go = Redirected to page "AX"
eg: Select teacher: ..B... , Select class: ..Y......, Go = Redirected to page "AY"

So I'd like to combine selection A + B, so how to list selections and how to call the inputs to take an action and redirects? It's going to be inputted in one of the wordpress pages (Text Section) and will hyperlinked/anchortagged to other pages.


 A quick try:

```
<form action="page.php" method="POST" name="drop_list"><select name="Category" onchange="SelectSubCat();">
<option value="">Category A</option>
<option value="">Option A</option>
</select>
<select id="SubCat" name="SubCat" onchange="SelectRedirect();">
<option value="">Category B</option>
<option value="">Option B</option>
</select>

</form>&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery for this. I have added code.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#btn', function() {
            var website_url = 'your_website_url';
            var segment_1 = parseInt($('#ParentCat').val());
            var segment_2 = parseInt($('#SubCat').val());
            var total = segment_1 * segment_2;
            window.location = website_url + '/' + total;
        });
    });
</script>

<form action="" method="POST" name="drop_list">
<select name="Category" id="ParentCat">
<option value="">Category A</option>
<option value="">Option A</option>
</select>
<select id="SubCat" name="SubCat">
<option value="">Category B</option>
<option value="">Option B</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome :) Thank you very much, never thought about jquery. Just a question though where do I get to define the page links based on the combinations?

Comment: You can define website_url above segment_1. I have added in code. Please see it.

Comment: @AhmadHussien Glad to help you.

Comment: Just one more question, this function does calls Category%20B instead of the value inside the tag so `<option value="local-procurement">Local Procurement</option>` is returning Local%20Procurement instead of local-procurement . Is there anything missing to be modified in the "segment" variable?

Comment: You should try var segment_1 = $('#ParentCat option:selectedt').val(); and var segment_2 = $('#SubCat option:selectedt').val(); instead of old one.